# When Working with Jquery Mobile, HTML A HREF Keeps adding # and base url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Ok,

I'm at my wit's end here. I've read the questions around anchor tags, base url's and the usage of / in a href. Yet no matter what I do, I still seem to get an anchor tag and base url added to the link.

**Example below:**
When I hover over the Link, it shows 
http://www.localhost:8080/view/login.php
but when I click on the a href tag I get this below
http://www.localhost:8080/view/register.php#/view/login.php

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Food Loginator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css">
        <link href="../CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../Javascript/gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Javascript/pwdwidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Food Loginator</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/index.php" data-icon="home" data-theme="b" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/view/login.php" data-icon="star" data-theme="b" >Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/view/register.php" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-active">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</header>
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a default part of the JQuery mobile functionality. Apparently, JQuery does an Ajax call to the object with the #tag in the a tag. It then dynamically add's that object to the DOM. In order to remove it i had to add  rel="external" to my a tags.

https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Answer (score 0):

set the links href='#'

and add an onclick event call that uses changePage

```
function pagechange () {
$.mobile.changePage('index.php');
}
```

Comment: Why would I do that? If I understand correctly. I'd have to put a function for each page, vesus just adding rel="external". I ask this out of honest curiosity, not out of snarkiness.